# GRUB rescue returns no such partition after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, grubrescue

I have dual booted Windows 10 and ubuntu. I accidently deleted the ubuntu partition from Disk Management from my Windows. After restarting my laptop, I get the following error:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

`ls` returns:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)
```

When I entered `ls (hd0,msdos1)`

I get error: `(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is unknown`

`set` command returns:

```
cmdpath = (hd0)
prefix = (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root = hd0,msdos5
```

When `ls` command returns only `(hd0,msdos1)` , why set is showing as `(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub`

[Here is what is showing on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xpPB.jpg)

Comment: Try this: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/error-no-such-partition.html

Comment: @GaneshKathiresan The solution on the mentioned site requires a USB , but right now I do not have any USB drive with me.